# wordpress django currenct_active_page

Tags: django, django-templates, wordpress-theming

in wordpress your template automatically kicks out a '.current_page_item' on your menu.

I am wondering if there is a django way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Well django is not wordpress and also not a cms, but it could be used as one.

In this case you have to do on your own, it will depends how you designed your templates?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this and it depends on how you are doing your menus.  I usually create my menu as a Django model.  Then, in my template I compare the current path with the menu path.  eg.

```
<ul class="menu">
{% for m in menuitems %}
    <li{% if m.path == request.path }} class="current"{% endif %}>
        <a href="{{ m.path }}">{{ m.title }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Of cause, you would need to pass in menuitems into your view.  To save adding in that into all my views, I usually create a template tag that fetches the menuitems variable for me.

So yes, completely possible... but it completely depends on how you decide to structure your menus and pages.  Django is a web-framework, whereas Wordpress is a Blog engine.